# How can I draw datapoints on boxplot with different color using plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot

I was trying to draw a boxplot with all the points on it. I need to use multiple colors to show multiple dimensions.

1. Three boxes with three colors (say, January, February, March in X axis)
2. Some values in Y
3. All the points in different (Say, different temperatures - 10 steps in 10) colors   << This is the challenge I am confused with.
4. In the legend only color-point should appear << Also this.

I could do it in ggplot. Tried to convert ggplot to plotly like this,
qq <- ggplotly(gg). It does not work, legends just break.

Could you please drop some light on it? Thank you.

[image: Sample graph done in ggplot]

Comment: can you share some example data/code you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @timfaber,
Thanks. Its n ggplot. I am trying same in plotly. Thank you. Sample code may help?

gg <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(mtcars$gear), y=mtcars$carb)) 
gg <- gg + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = as.factor(mtcars$gear), alpha = .4 )) 
gg <- gg +  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(width=0.15), alpha=0.2, aes(color= as.factor(mtcars$cyl) ))

gg <- gg + ggtitle("Some kind of distribution") 
gg <- gg + labs(x="Some months as example", y="Some score to y axis", color = "Color is to show more dimension") + guides(alpha = FALSE, fill = FALSE ) 
gg <- gg + theme_bw() 

gg

Comment: Main problem is with plotly's marker color. The 'color' class, overrides the marker color or, I do not know how to pass a list of variable colors to markers.

Comment: Oei yes, for some reason it coerces color/fill to be a single response option, confusing, I ll have a look!